# GNU `find` error: "find: failed to read file names from file system at or below ‘/’ : No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, macos, find, gnu, coreutils

OS: macOS Big Sur 11.6

I'm trying to find all files on my system that match a pattern so I can delete extraneous files after removing an application. For this purpose the application is RStudio.

I'm using this GNU `find` command to find all files or directories containing the pattern "`rstudio`":

```bsh
find / -name "*rstudio*"
```

However, I get an error before all matching files are found that says:

```
find: failed to read file names from file system at or below ‘/’ : No such file or directory
```

This error seems to appear after `find` has only searched `/usr/...`, `/Library/...`, and `/System/...`.

I know for a fact there are items containing the pattern in e.g. `~/.local`, `~/.share`, and `~/.config` like `~/.config/rstudio/`, but these are never found.

Yes I am using `gfind` installed with Homebrew and aliased to `find` and not the macOS `/usr/bin/find`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have an answer, sorry, but I have a similar problem I have asked at [After upgrade to Catalina getting error " gfind: failed to read..." - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/426465/after-upgrade-to-catalina-getting-error-gfind-failed-to-read-file-names-from). See also  [gupdatedb fails with "gfind: failed to read..." - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/397015/gnu-version-of-locate-gupdatedb-fails-with-gfind-failed-to-read-file-names-f).

Comment: I wonder if this could be related to SIP? Which is another way of wondering if the GNU ports are aware of the read-only part of the file system?

Answer (score 0):

not an answer but maybe a WORKAROUND.
The problem seems to be around for some years.
I have it on Windows, with MSYS2,
where I use VeraCrypt Volumes, mounted on Z:, Y:, X:, ...
**First:**
I have the problem *only* when searching **a** ( not "in a") Top-Level-Folder

```
mkdir -p /x/aaa/{bbb,ccc}
cd /x/aaa
find . => ERROR
find bbb/ => OK
cd bbb
find .    => OK
find ../  => ERROR
find ../ccc => OK
```

**Second:**
I have the problem on `exFat`, but **not on `NTFS`**.

So the 2nd is my  Workaround: format USB-Drives and VeraCrypt-Volumes to NTFS.
Both 1st and 2nd are hopefully helpful to fix this problem - some day :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have had to stop using the GNU findutils version. At this time, there isn't really a workaround other than revert back to using the BSD based version that comes with macOS e.g

```
alias find='/usr/bin/find’ # use macOS version
```

I am not sure why the GNU version has this issue perhaps it's something to do with APFS.

There are also some alternatives to ‘find' which may work as a workaround these include fd, mdfind (using macOS spotlight) or locate/locatedb.

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question raised. It should be better a comment on the question itself. Please delete your answer and post it as a comment, or, if you believe your workaround to be an appropriate answer, format it as such.
Thank you and welcome to SuperUser.

Comment: @ComputerUser121212 currently there isn't a solution to using GNU find unless the OP can rewrite it. The workarounds given are alternatives. I have tried to rewrite as an answer to explain this. It is a valid answer depending on the context which you apply it.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Just wanted to make sure you understood how the site works. Thank you for your participation.

Comment: Apologies if I was a bit blunt. Yeah I have been a member of a few stack exchange sites for years. I totally misread your motive and I now know you were only trying to help. Thanks